# What's a bin.net3.5 file

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

What's a 'bin.net3.5' file that gets created in the same folder as the VS2012 solution that contains an ASP.net website?

I would like to mention that this is a file and I am not referring to the project's 'bin' directory where projects' compiled dlls will be placed after a build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed it seems that this is something related to your project specific file. There is no such standard file created by Visual Studio 2012

**[Bin Folder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295391.aspx)**

> ASP.NET recognizes the Bin folder of a website as a special folder for
>   specific types of content. A Bin folder is meant to contain compiled
>   assemblies (.dll files) for custom ASP.NET controls, components, or
>   other code that you want to reference in your ASP.NET web application.
>
> You can store compiled assemblies in the Bin folder, and other code
>   anywhere in the web application (such as code for pages) automatically
>   references it. A typical example is that you have the compiled code
>   for a custom class. You can copy the compiled assembly to the Bin
>   folder of your Web application and the class is then available to all
>   pages.

Comment: Sorry.. I was referring to the 'bin.net3.5' file and not the bin folder which is in the project folder. This bin.net3.5 file got created one level above and in the same level as the solution file.

Comment: As far as my knowledge is concerned there is no such file created while creating a website in Visual Studio. Is this file getting created in your Website folder and for every website which you are creating??

Comment: Only one file got created for the solution. When I created a separate branch of the solution after deleting this file and rebuilt it there, again it got created. Was wondering what this is.

Comment: This is what I see in the explorer "bin.net3.5     date    Type: 5 file 1,855KB". Must be taking 5 after the '.' incorrectly as an extension.

Comment: Didnt get that...What you see??

Comment: I've updated the comment. I think I hit enter to put the text in a new line.

Comment: I am quite confident that it is your project specific file. It is not a standard file which is created in Visual Studio. Also the file size is 1855 KB which is appreciably large!!!

Comment: Possibly. When I went thro' other solutions, I don't see it there. This solution was recently upgraded from 3.5 to 4. Not sure if that has something to do with it. Thank you, Rahul. Appreciate your time.

Comment: You are welcome. Thats what I was telling you that it is something related to your project specific thing!!! :) P.S. Adding this in my answer too!!

Answer (score 1):

Some `DLL's` are kept in different folder names to determine the version, you'll notice when using nuget, the dll's will go into a **packages folder**, and are often split as `net40`, `net45` etc

When you build the project, your Dll's will go into the `Bin` directory.